# How to stop Jenkins polling SVN source control?

Tags: jenkins, svn

I have a Jenkins server building our project and there's a data section that gets checked out from source control (SVN). I changed it to try to stop it being included in source control polling (poll: false) however I can see changes to the repository are still triggering builds.

Have I got the syntax correct here? I added "poll: false" but it's being ignored.

```
stage('Data Checkout')
{
    dir('E:\\workspace\\data') 
    {
        checkout([
            poll: false,
            scm: [$class: 'SubversionSCM', 
            additionalCredentials: [], 
            excludedCommitMessages: '', 
            excludedRegions: '', 
            excludedRevprop: '', 
            excludedUsers: '', 
            filterChangelog: false, 
            ignoreDirPropChanges: false, 
            includedRegions: '', 
            locations: [[credentialsId: 'xxx', 
               depthOption: 'infinity', 
               ignoreExternalsOption: true, 
               local: 'local',
               remote: "svn://xxx/data"]], 
            workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateUpdater']]])
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, do you have any post-commit hooks in your SVN `$REPOSITORY/hooks` directory ? If not, you could try to see if slightly modified syntax works instead`checkout poll: false, scm: [$class: 'SubversionSCM', additionalCredentials: [], excludedCommitMessages: '', excludedRegions: '', excludedRevprop: '', excludedUsers: '', filterChangelog: false, ignoreDirPropChanges: false, includedRegions: '', locations: [[credentialsId: 'xxx', depthOption: 'infinity', ignoreExternalsOption: true, local: 'local', remote: "svn://xxx/data"]], workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateUpdater']]`

Comment: I see an error reported: unexpected token: false. Taking out the brackets doesn't help.